# get authorization status of FaceId in swift IOS

Tags: swift, face-id

Can we get status of FaceId in our app, for example somebody use faceId for opening phone, he or she opens my app and i want to check he or she uses faceId for authorization somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean if they use FaceID for authentication into the phone or if they are using FaceID to open other apps?

Comment: anywhere if faceid used i want to get status of faceId, authorization succed of failed if any app or phone uses